# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

im getting "Trying to get property 'selleruserid' of non-object" this error. How can i resolve this error?

```
$selleruserid= 0;


$featured['items'] = Items::with('Ratings')->select('items.item_id', 'items.user_id AS selleruserid', 'items.item_liked','items.item_slug','items.item_preview','items.item_name','items.item_type','users.user_photo','users.username','users.user_document_verified','items.updated_item','items.item_sold','items.free_download','items.item_flash','items.item_type_cat_id','items.regular_price','items.item_token', 'items.mainpage_boost_last')->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')->where('items.item_status','=',1)->where('items.mainpage_boost_last','>', $today_date)->where('items.drop_status','=','no')->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take($setting['setting']->home_featured_items)->get();


$selleruserid = $featured->selleruserid; // ERROR LINE


$checkuser = Items::checkuser($selleruserid);
```

I will be glad if you help me thank you

Comment: `$featured` is apparently an array as shown in line 2, you cannot use it as an object in line 3.

Comment: `$selleruserid = $featured['items']->selleruserid;` maybe?

Comment: @aynber what should i use? $featured->selleruserid how can i extract this information

Comment: @Skip Probably not since they're using `get()`, which returns a collection instead of a single result. They'd have to iterate over `$featured['items']`

Comment: Did you check $featured with var_dump?

Comment: dd($featured['items']); and check the result if result is not empty.then access it like $featured['items']->selleruserid maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your assignment, the line:
`$selleruserid = $featured->selleruserid;`

Should be:
`$selleruserid = $featured['items']->selleruserid;`

If you still have the same error, then `Items::with('Ratings')->...` isn't returning anything.